# Convert java mjpeg stream bytes to an image

Tags: java, android, mjpeg

I'm receiving an mjpeg stream from the WiRC.

The WiRC document describes the following about the stream:

```
Camera image format      JPEG
Camera image resolution  CIF: 352 × 288
```

The documentation describes the following:

### Packet specification

The protocol uses UDP packets to transfer the MJPEG stream. The MJPEG stream consists of
independent JPEG frames. A JPEG frame is sent in several packets. The fragment size is determined by the server application.

The first 16 bytes of a packet is the header. The packet header has four fields containing 32-bit words in network byte order (big-endian).

```
name        offset  width    description
version     0       32 bit   protocol version and flags  
frame num   4       32 bit   bit index of the JPEG frame in the stream
offset      8       32 bit   offset of the packet data in the JPEG frame
length      12      32 bit   number of data bytes in the packet beyond the header
```

### Version field

Flags are encoded in the upper 16 bit of the version field, the lower 16-bit
contains the version number (mind the host byte order during interpreting the
version field).

```
name                  bits     description
reserved flag bits    31..17   these bits shall be ignored
last packet flag      16       if set this is the last packet of a JPEG frame
version information   15..0    Protocol version, expected value is 0x5503
```

I'm using the following code for decoding the stream to an image:

```java
int offset = ((int)(bytes[8]  & 255) << 24) |
             ((int)(bytes[9]  & 255) << 16) |
             ((int)(bytes[10] & 255) <<  8) |
             ((int)(bytes[11] & 255));
int length = ((bytes[12]  & 255) << 24) |
             ((bytes[13]  & 255) << 16) |
             ((bytes[14]  & 255) <<  8) |
             ((bytes[15]  & 255));
long frame = ((bytes[4]  & 255) << 24) |
             ((bytes[5]  & 255) << 16) |
             ((bytes[6]  & 255) <<  8) |
             ((bytes[7]  & 255));

System.out.printf("Version: 0x%02X 0x%02X", bytes[2], bytes[3]);

Boolean last = (bytes[1]   &   1) == 1 ? true : false;

System.out.println(" Offset: "+offset+" Length: "+length);
System.out.println("Lastpacket: "+last + " framenum: "+frame);
System.out.println();

Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,32,length);
```

However this keeps returning a message that the BitmapFactory failed

Any ideas or sugestions?

---

I get the following responce on the console:

```
UDP received stuff
Version:  0x5503    Offset:     0    Length: 7584
Lastpacket: true    framenum: 223
```

Edit: Changed code and added console outcome

Comment: Saw a little fail in the start size, was 128 where it should have been 32. Changed this, gonna test again tomorrow

Comment: Where do you reassamble the frames? Looks to me you're trying to decode only portions of the frames. Remember they are fragmented. If you do reassemble, please add that code.

Comment: I don't do any reassambling, I expected some kind of counter of some sort to tell me what frame I'm looking add.

Comment: So what I would need to do would be just merge frames till I get a last packet flag?

Comment: You have frame num in the header. As soon as it changes, it's another frame. And remember: UDP can be out of order! Oh, yes and the flag ... so use the frame number and offsets for ordering.

Comment: Where is the frame number located? The specification doesn't have anything about this and the offset is always 0.

Comment: Nevermind I see the frame number but the offset is always zero tho.

Comment: Do framenumber rise? Then the image could be small enough for one packet. In that case, the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Every 4 bytes: little endian or big endian? Instead of 8,9,10,11 it might be 11,10,9,8 etc. Compare with plausible/checkable value like version.

Comment: @JoopEggen "in network byte order (big-endian)". At least for the header, it is in the question.

Comment: Edited question showing version bytes, could the image bytes be flipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own bug. I was building images this way:

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 32, length);
```

Where it should have been:

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 16, length);
```

The rest was done right.

However thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG images are fragmented over UDP Packets and UDP Packets can be out of order.

So you'll have to look at the headers:

- Frame number: Same number - same frame
- Offset : Ordering inside frame
- Last Packet flag: The frame number of this packet is the last in the frame.

Now you have to work out how to put them together. I guess offset will start from 0 for each frame, so it should be fairly easy to come up with something.

Remember to build in some timeout mechanism, since UDP is not reliable.

For example: If you have Frame x still not complete and Frame x+1 is already complete, just ditch it. Or you will end up having a memory full of incomplete images :)

----EDIT----

You may want to consider using a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). It has very convenient methods to deal with byteorder and int / long whatever conversion from bytes.

Comment: I see, I'll look into this. However for as far as I have seen the offset is always 0.

Comment: See my comment above. It could be that small images fit into one package. Does the size make some sense? And do framenumbers rise?

Comment: By the way: If those are "unsigned integers", you should use long in Java.

Comment: Each frame contains the last frame bit for as far as I can see. The frame counters are going up nicely. The version is read properly when I read the bytes: 2 and 3 so appartantly that one is switched. Would this mean that the image bytes are flipped aswell?

Comment: Wouldn't this mean flipping the length aswell? That gives me a frame size of `2016935936` which doesn't seem likely to me.

Comment: Wait, what? What do you mean exactly with "flipping"? Everything should be in big endian. The version is bits 15-0 ... So if you read bytes 2 and 3 and the conversion is correct, why is it "flipped" then?

Answer (score 0):

For better use of mjpeg stream, you should use libjpeg library.
or this demp project 
http://www.anddev.org/resources/file/1484